# User Categories, User:Edit Expected Behavior

Tags: solspace-user

I'm using categories in a user:edit tag and also in a user:profile tag on separate templates. In the user:profile template the categories that the user is assigned to appear, however in the user:edit template the checkbox for the assigned category is not selected. Should it be? All other member data is populating as expected.

I'm using this code from the example as a test:

```
{categories}
    {category_selected}selected="selected"{/category_selected}
    {category_body}
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]"
        value="{category_id}" {selected} /> {category_name}
    {/category_body}
{/categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a checkbox, you should be using `checked` instead, so something like this:

```
{categories}
    {category_selected}checked="checked"{/category_selected}
    {category_body}
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]"
        value="{category_id}" {selected} /> {category_name}
    {/category_body}
{/categories}
```